# How to warp 3D model to take into account horizon curvature?

Tags: qgis, 3d-model, curvature

I am using USGS Astrogeology data for the Moon's south pole. Here's the same dataset at half resolution: 
"LRO_LOLA_DEM_SPolar875_10m.tif (tif) 278 MB" [on this page](https://astrogeology.usgs.gov/search/details/Moon/LRO/LOLA/Lunar_LRO_LOLA_Global_LDEM_118m_Mar2014/cub).

I already have a process for converting the GeoTIFF into a 3D model, but because the GeoTIFF is a map of planet radii, it doesn't include any horizon curvature. This results in the outer extents of it being more than a kilometer above the actual terrain. How should I correct for this?

QGIS GeoTIFF info: 
[image: geotiff info]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using two Simple Deform -> Bend modifiers in Blender to do this. I made empties at the mesh origin to hold position and rotation as input, with a different angle for each.

Comment: I recommend actually going into the math using some projection reference materials; this was just quick and dirty to get some visuals.